# App Store email varies from Apple ID, where can this be set up on iPad Pro

Tags: ios-appstore

When setting up new iPad Pro-by default it only permits one email address to be used for Apple ID & App Store. On all my other devices, I have one email associated with my Apple ID & a different email address associated with my App Store. Because I haven’t been able to locate where one can make this distinction, in Settings (or elsewhere), I can’t access any of my previously purchased apps. Any one run into this or know how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

When setting up your iPad, there's a button on the Apple ID login page to log in with separate iCloud and iTunes Apple IDs.

If you didn't press this link, you can retroactively change your iTunes & App Stores Apple ID in Settings:

1. Go to Settings, tap your name at the top of the list, then choose iTunes & App Stores.
2. Choose the Apple ID displayed at the top, then Sign Out.
3. Sign in with the Apple ID you wish to use.